# How do i calculate a variable total PHP on while loop?

Tags: php

i need to get total of a variable which is in while loop, i have tried with "+=", but i dont know if i have done it right because it was showing me 2 values.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM open_trades WHERE user_id='$session->username' ORDER BY `close_time` DESC ";
 $result = $db->prepare($sql);
 $result->execute(); 
 
 while ($row = $result->fetch()) {

    if ($row["type"] == "Buy") {
       $profit_c = (float) $row["volume"] * (float) $row["live_price"] - $row["cost"];
       $fee = 4.9; 
       $profit = $profit_c * $row["laverage"] - $fee;
       
    } 
    
    if ($row["type"] == "Sell") { 
       $profit_c = (float) $row["volume"] * (float) $row["live_price"] - $row["cost"]; 
       $fee = 4.9; 
       $profit = $profit_c * $row["laverage"] - $fee; 
       $profit_sell = $profit * -1;
    } 
       
    if ($row["type"] == "Buy") { 
       $profit_trd = $profit; 
    } else { 
       $profit_trd = $profit_sell;
    }
       
    if ($profit_trd >= 0) { 
       $col = "profit"; 
       } else { 
       $col = "loss";
    } 

    if ($profit_trd >= 0) { 
       $col_b = "#26b276"; 
    } else { 
       $col_b = "#f73e4a";
    }
       
    $percentage = ((float) $profit_trd * 100) / (float) $row["cost"]; 

    echo '<tr style="border-right: 2px solid ' . $col_b . ';" class="d-flex justify-content-between" >'; 
    echo "<td>" . $row["time"] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row["asset"] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row["type"] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . (float) $row["volume"] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>1:" . $row["laverage"] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . (float) $row["buy_price"] . '$</td>'; 
    echo "<td>" . (float) $row["live_price"] . '$</td>'; 
    echo "<td>" . (float) round($row["cost"], 2) . '$</td>'; 
    echo '<td class="' . $col . '" >' . (float) round($profit_trd, 2) . '$</td>'; 
    echo "<td>Close Trade</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; }
    ?>
```

I need to get total of $profit_trd of all rows, on my try it showes the value of last row and the value i need, ex. last value 100, total 500, it was showing me 100500.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly did you try? I don't see any ` +=` in your code. Show your attempt, and then we can help you to fix it. That's how Stackoverflow works. Thanks.

Comment: If it's showing the value twice, you're probably showing the variable inside the loop. The total should only be shown at the end.

Comment: This is a calculation that's better done by the database. Look to improve your query, and return the data you want already summarised

Comment: @Barmar That was the problem, now its solved, Thanks everyone!